# GCS Cloning GitHub Repos to Compute Engine VM

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a basic question on my first attempt to deploy a Node.js app on Google Cloud Services using a Compute Engine Virtual Machine.

I have created a Google Cloud Repository of my GitHub code. I have tried to clone this repo onto my virtual machine. When I do it, I show the repo name, but that directory is empty.

[image]

Am I supposed to have the actual files inside this directory, or is it some link to the Google Cloud Repo and it only appears empty? If the files are supposed to physically be in this directory, that could explain why I can't get my startup script to run.

And if they are supposed to be in there, I'm not sure why they don't clone but it could be because my path to default code GitHub is messed up.

Thanks in advance. I have been stuck on this for too long.

EDIT:
I used: `I used gcloud source repos clone github_sleepywakes_thunderroost --project=imposing-timer-334919`
to clone my repo

When I use it again, I get this message:

```
WARNING: Repository "github_sleepywakes_thunderroost" in project "imposing-timer-334919" is a mirror. Pushing to this clone will have no effect.  Instead, clone the mirrored repository directly with
$ git clone https://github.com/SleepyWakes/ThunderRoost
Cloning into '/home/overlord/github_sleepywakes_thunderroost'...
remote: Total 1581 (delta 264), reused 1581 (delta 264)
Receiving objects: 100% (1581/1581), 3.43 MiB | 9.59 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (264/264), done.
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

So it appears my files are copied, but when I change directory into github_sleepywakes_thunderroost and ls, the directory is empty.

Comment: What command did you use? Do not use screenshots. Copy the text into your question. Your screenshot shows that you are running on CloudShell, which is a VM and the environment is managed differently than a Compute Engine instance.

Comment: I used `gcloud source repos clone github_sleepywakes_thunderroost --project=imposing-timer-334919`

Comment: And what was the output from that command? Edit your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: The problem is **Directory path specified exists and is not empty**. The directory should not exist. If it does exist it **must** be empty. Solution: delete the directory that git is cloning into.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I deleted the directory and re-cloned the repository to show the original issue of not seeing any files in my new cloned directory. Original post edited with more helpful details.

Comment: The clone failed **remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout**. You are probably specifying an incorrect repository name/path.

Comment: Many thanks John Hanley for walking me through to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My GitHub repository brand was named "main" rather than "master." Google Cloud Shell apparently looks for master so could not link to the correct path. In GitHub, I deleted the main branch and pushed my code to a new repository called master. I then was able to clone the GitHub repository.

There are likely other ways to fix this.